# Creating global permissions variable after user authorization in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I would like to set global variable after the user is authenticated -  lets call it `permissions`. The variable should be available in controllers and views.

What is the best way to achieve it? Now in each method I have to perform database query and check user roles which is not optimal.

I know that I can declare `view::share` method in appserviceprovider to pass the variable to views, but boot method is performed after the user is authenticated.

**Update**

I've created BaseController which extends from Controller.

BaseController:

```
class BaseController extends Controller {

  public $permissions;

  public function __construct() {
      $this->permissions = GroupRoles::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
  }

}
```

Then I'm trying to access the permissions variable from UserController which extends from BaseController. Getting the trying to get access of non-object. I think it's because the BaseController constructor is contructed before the middleware.

```
class UserController extends BaseController {

  public function showPermissions() {
    return var_dump($this->permissions);
  }

}
```

**The final solution**

The cornerstone was to use the `$this->middleware(function ($request, $next)` in the BaseController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it within the controller or create your own BaseController then extend your controllers from it and in the BaseController you can do like this

```
public $permissions;

public function __construct()
{
   $permissions = Permissions::all() //For example
   $this->permissions = $permissions
}
```

Then you can access it from every controller like this `$this->permissions`

Comment: I've created BaseController and constructor with it. But I still can't access the permissions variable from UserController. I think that I should do something more than that. Because I'm getting the `Trying to get property of non-object` error. So the problem is still connected to authentication.

Comment: But are you tryin` to set permssion from package ? User Controller must extends BaseController so you can get it. Or first try do dump the var in the constructor so you can be sure that the data you want is there.

Comment: UserController extends the BaseController. BaseController extends the Controller. I'm getting this error because the construct method is called before the Auth method is loaded or I don't know how to call it. The BaseController has the following code in constructor: `$this->permissions = GroupRoles::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->first();`